# I can't open gufw in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bug-reporting, 16.04, gufw

** (gufw.py:28335): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libgbm.so.1: 無法開啟共用目的檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄

/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py:117: Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type 'void'

self.web_content = WebKit.WebView()

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw.py", line 29, in

```
gufw = Gufw(controler.get_frontend())
```

File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 79, in **init**

```
self._set_objects_name()
```

File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 117, in _set_objects_name

```
self.web_content = WebKit.WebView()
```

TypeError: could not get a reference to type class

Comment: How did you get the gufw installed?

Comment: From Ubuntu's repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4fvzui/cant_start_gufw_on_ubuntu_1604_heres_the_solution/) says that it's because of a broken dependency and the fix for that is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject
```

After typing that in a terminal, I'm now able to start GUFW.

Comment: You can answer this too.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/760292/gufw-on-ubuntu-16-04-dont-run