# gufw on ubuntu 16.04 don't run

Tags: firewall, gufw

It doesn't run properly when I click and closes automatically.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gui-ufw/+bug/1573567

Comment: It is my bug report.

Comment: Was failing to open too for me on **arch Linux** with the icon so I ran `sudo gufw` from the terminal and it launched just fine

Answer (score 1):

This [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4fvzui/cant_start_gufw_on_ubuntu_1604_heres_the_solution/) says that it's because of a broken dependency and the fix for that is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject
```

After typing that in a terminal, I'm now able to start GUFW.

Comment: python-gi works, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it today (`2016.05.06`) and everything works fine.

I'm using GUFW version `16.04.1`, Ubuntu `16.04` with kernel `4.4.0-21-generic`.

I already had the package `python-gi` installed at version `3.20.0-0ubuntu1`

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem in Debian Stretch RC3. Basic setup. What fixed it was  net-tools package.

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Would you please expand this answer a bit?  Why would the net-tools package help, and how would the OP go about installing / using it?